# Best/up-to-date ways to create a captive portal

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, captive-portal

So, I want to make a captive portal. For that I have 2 routers in my arsenal.
An old ISP-provided Thompson modem/router TG585 v.8 (DSL line goes there) and a recently purchased Linksys E2500 N600 v.3 router.

I flashed the Linksys with DDWRT firmware; I can create & manage a captive portal from DDWRT and a computer running the required servers and my Java code.

By the means of which software/service/technology would the captive portal be the most stable and up to date? (For example chillispot, sputnik, HTTP redirect ...). In addition, is it worth approaching this with a DDWRT (or OpenWrt/Tomato - explain if so) router or is there another alternative you have in mind that's worth considering?

Finally, which would be the right approach for something like this? A network setup of 1 LAN with 1 gateway and 1 access point or 2 bridged LANs (private and guest) where the private has the gateway and the guest handles the captive portal users?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for openwrt, I also used it as same as you want and its working like a charm. I used Tp-Link WR841Nv11 router and edit coova-chilli settings from this [link](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.coova-chilli).